# I want to know how we can control the simulated temperature sensor in ibm bluemix using python

Tags: ibm-cloud, iot, ibm-cloud-plugin, watson-iot, openstack-python-api

I want to know how I can get logs from simulated temperature and humidity sensor in ibmbluemix quickstart device. I can only see that it is done using java script. I couldnt find a place to write my python code that would interact with the simulated temperature sensor.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your question, I don't think it's clear enough. Are you looking to write python code to simulate temperature and sensor data? In that case you can refer to our python client library documentation at the link - https://docs.internetofthings.ibmcloud.com/devices/libraries/python.html

If not, can you please elaborate on your question and mention clearly what are you looking for?

Thanks,
Loki..,

Comment: Your answer is more suitable for a comment.